# How to read json variable "@odata.context" in Java using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

In Json, i have following

```
{  "@odata.context":"https://te.avolutionsoftware.com/api/$metadata#Components/$entity"
```

When i translate Json to java i get following:

```
private String @odata.context;
```

and compiler is not allowing that.

Any idea how to read this variable particularly in Gson library or in general what to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SerializedName might help you . like this:

```html
public final class Context {
        @SerializedName("@odata.context")
        public String context;
    
    }
```